# Create a spy in Jasmine with a specific arity

Tags: javascript, jasmine

How can I create a spy in Jasmine with a specific arity?

`jasmine.createSpy` and `spyOn(myObject, 'myMethod')` returns a function with an arity of zero.

Comment: Regretfully it doesn't seem like current versions of Jasmine (<= 2.2) can do this.

Comment: Could you wrap the spy in a function with the desired arity and pass that in place of the spy?